# Unable to detect second monitor via HDMI port

Tags: debian, display, xrandr, monitors, hdmi

Fairly new to the Linux world but any support from the community would be appreciated.

The core of the issue is I'm having a hard time understanding why my laptop isn't able to detect a secondary monitor attached via HDMI. Troubleshooting information is displayed below:

**uname -a**

Linux Debi 4.19.0-16-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.19.181-1 (2021-03-19) i686 GNU Linux

**xrandr --listmonitors**

xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

Monitors: 1

0: +*default i368/362x768/203+0+0 default

**xrandr**

xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

Screen 0: minimum 1366 x 768, current 1368 x 768, maximum 1368 x 768 default connected primary 1368x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm

1366x768     0.00

1366x768     0.00*

Comment: How many external monitors do you have plugged in?

Comment: I have one monitor attached.